# Java Lambda Expression to UpperCase string value within an Object

Tags: java, lambda

I have a lambda expression in which I use a UnaryOperator to convert a string value into uppercase, if not null:

```
public static final UnaryOperator toUpperCase
    = (str -> str == null ? str : str.toString().toUpperCase());
```

I then use this Operator within a method and pass in the Object, the getter, and the setter. With those parameters I can get the object (string), uppercase the string, and then set the string to the value:

```
 public static final void convertToUpper(Object1 object1, Function<Object1, String> getter,
         BiConsumer<Object1, String> setter) { 
     setter.accept(object1, toUpperCase.apply(getter.apply(object1)).toString()); 
 }
```

However, for every object I want this conversion on, I have to create another `convertToUpper` method with different object parameters. Is there a way to make this method more generic and allow any object, getter, and setter to be passed in. The problem I am running into is the getters/setters are not static, and cannot be referenced without their object declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `convertToUpper` a generic method:

```
public static final <T> void convertToUpper(T object1, Function<? super T, String> getter,
        BiConsumer<? super T, String> setter) {
    setter.accept(object1, toUpperCase.apply(getter.apply(object1)).toString());
}
```

You can pass in any object, getter and setter, as long as that getter and setter can be applied to that type of object.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper What do you mean?

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part.